# Count of Users Grouped by Date with Exposed Filter

Tags: 7, datetime, views

I want to create a view that shows the count of users grouped by date. That works fine by just adding aggregation and using the "count" function.

As soon as I add an exposed filter to narrow down the date range the grouping doesn't work anymore.

I've come across recommendations to turn of the RDF module but that didn't fix the issue.

Has anyone else come across this issue?